# Is the Stack Exchange team now getting paid more than slave wages?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, payment

Since the beginning of Stack Overflow, Jeff Atwood has been saying that the team have been paid slave wages. With the success of Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User et al has this changed?

Has the team moved up to serf or possibly even pauper wages?

**Note**: I posted this question not to be nosy, though it obviously could be construed that way, but out of interest in that I love these sites and wanted to know if all the hard work is paying some dividends for the team.

I have been working my way through all the Stack Overflow podcasts, starting with episode one as I came late to the party and kept hearing Jeff talk about how the team has been doing it for the love of it on slave wages. I have now got to episode 23 and while the sites appear to be very popular and *successful* (still going) I was hoping that things are working out well for the team hence my question.

Comment: Slave labour wages of which country base?

Comment: Good point random. I guess within the context of US programming slave wages.

Comment: `success of StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser`? Well I do think it's a success, where else was the success mentioned? Just curious.

Comment: By success I mean the obvious that StackOverflow is still going and very popular so much so that they have branched out.

Comment: Maybe it's not as successful as you think and that's why they're branching out to find other revenue streams? Not sure why the obsession with private financial matters like this. Just sayin'.

Comment: Kev, not obsessed but more interested and hoping that all the effort that has gone into the site(s) is paying some dividends for the team.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, almost all the money that comes in goes to salaries. That's order of business #1, pay what people are worth!

Comment: Good to hear Jeff. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Don't spend it all on stickers!

Comment: those stickers were an *investment*, man! In our future!!

Comment: Jeff by your own goals and measurements I take it that you and the team see the StackOverflow empire a success?

Comment: Stickers @ SQLPASS, photo compliments of mrdenny http://www.flickr.com/photos/mrdenny/4072020233/in/set-72157622726310110/

Comment: The order of business #2 is pay people that are wroth.

Answer (score 17):

They should be getting "industry competitive" wages in about 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Is this an inside joke or is it based on hard numbers?

Comment: Inside joke: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this is short and sweet, but I don't think that's really any of our business to be honest.

Comment: I'm not asking to know how much they get paid but more that they are doing better than *slave wages*.

Comment: See Adams answer above.

Comment: Or below depending on your sorting preferences.